# In thunderbird, what are the key shortcuts to move up and down in the folder panel?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

In Mozilla Thunderbird, <kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>F</kbd> can be used to move up and down, respectively, in the thread pane. What are their counterparts for moving up and down in the folder pane?

Comment: FYI: What you called the "message panel" is actually called the "thread pane". See the "Thread pane" section on mozillaZine's page about [Window layout - Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Window_layout_-_Thunderbird#Thread_pane)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any built in keyboard shortcuts to do this directly.
The keyboard shortcuts available by default in Thunderbird are listed in [this documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts).

Indirectly, you can press the keyboard shortcut for "Move to Next Mail Pane": <kbd>F6</kbd> (which switches your keyboard focus between the visible mail panes) until the Folder pane is focused, then use the Up <kbd>↑</kbd> and Down <kbd>↓</kbd> arrow keys to move between folders.

If you really want a direct keyboard shortcut that always does exactly this function, you could install [Dorando Keyconfig](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/dorando-keyconfig/), add a new key, and write custom code to do what you want, but this seems like overkill to me when there is a simple, albeit indirect, method already available.

Comment: Late comment/reply to @3D1T0R, who said "this seems like overkill to me when there is a simple, albeit indirect, method already available".  I use speech recognition, Dragon commands that emit keyboard commands. These commands are essentially blind: they don't know what pane  has the focus. Such macros benefit from keyboard  commands that  are absolute, that put the UI in a known state - e.g. move focus to folder pane, topmost item -  rather than  relative commands like "move to next mail pane".

Answer (score 0):

I found these long functions seem to work with keyconfig:

Go to Next Folder:      Ctrl+]

```
{
  let folder = GetFirstSelectedMsgFolder();
  if (folder != null) {
    let index = gFolderTreeView.getIndexOfFolder(folder);
    if (index != null)
      folder = gFolderTreeView.getFolderForIndex(index + 1);
  }
  if (folder != null)
    gFolderTreeView.selectFolder(folder);
}
```

Go to Previous Folder:  Ctrl+[

```
{
  let folder = GetFirstSelectedMsgFolder();
  if (folder != null) {
    let index = gFolderTreeView.getIndexOfFolder(folder);
    if (index != null)
      folder = gFolderTreeView.getFolderForIndex(index - 1);
  }
  if (folder != null)
    gFolderTreeView.selectFolder(folder);
}
```

You can also assign one to go to home folder:

Go to Home:              Alt+Home

```
msgWindow.windowCommands.selectFolder("imap://xxxx/INBOX")
```

Find folder URI from javascript console with:

```
GetFirstSelectedMsgFolder().URI
```